# Simple HTML/JavaScript not saving cookie on harddrive

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

The following code is failing to result in a saved .txt cookie on my harddrive at the following location: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies`

I debug the page with Chrome element inspector and no cookie is showing up. Is there something I've misunderstood with creating a simple cookie?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
        document.cookie="username=test cookie; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC";
        alert("done");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding alert(document.cookie); as the first line, then refresh the page. First load should be blank, if the second load is that string, the cookie is being stored, just obviously not there.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the folder for Internet Explorer's cookies, not [Chrome's cookies](https://superuser.com/questions/292952/chrome-cookies-folder-in-windows-7).

Browsers may not support cookies from documents opened from `file://` URIs.